# How to delete a 2D vector of object pointers without a memory leak? C++ and SFML

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, sfml, 2d-vector

I have a 2D vector of Tile pointers. Each time I load a different map I would like to delete all the Tiles in the vector, freeing the memory, and then refill it with different tiles.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile*>> map;
```

Here is my Tile class:

```
#ifndef _TILE_H
#define _TILE_H

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Tile
{

public:
    int type;
    int color;
    int light_level;
    int loc_x, loc_y;

    Tile();
    ~Tile();

    sf::Sprite baseSprite;

    void Draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw);

    void setTexture(sf::Texture& texture);
};

#endif
```

I fill up the vectors like this:

```
map[x][y] = tile;
```

The problem is, each time I refill the vectors with Tiles my memory continues to fill up until the game crashes. My question is, how can I properly delete everything from the vectors so that the memory is freed?

Here is my attempt at deleting the tiles which did not free the memory:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < this->map.size(); ii++){
    for(int jj = 0; jj < this->h; jj++){

        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->baseSprite;
        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->color;
        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->light_level;
        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->loc_x;
        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->loc_y;
        delete &this->map[ii][jj]->type;

        delete &this->map[ii][jj];
    }
}


map.clear()
```

If any additional code is needed, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Not sure there's enough information to answer this well. But using smart pointers is probably not a bad idea.

Comment: You need to look up RAII. Deleting a tile should have a destructor that handles its members.

Comment: Take a look at smart-pointers, especially `std::unique_ptr`. If you cannot use that, look at the boost predecessor.

Comment: why are you deleting each member of `Tile`? they are not pointers themselves, you have **UB**.

Comment: Yeah, deleting each member of Tile isn't doing anything. I'm looking into std::unique_ptr

Comment: @OMGtechy I have a destructor for the Tile class. It doesn't seem to solve the problem though.

Comment: Your loop should contain only `delete this->map[ii][jj]` (without the extra `&`) if you don't use smart pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the `Tile` class, it seems silly to use `Tile` pointers instead of directly using `Tile`s in your vector. Here's a possible solution to your problem:

1. Define a copy constructor, i.e. define what `Tile::Tile(const Tile&)` should do (it should copy all the data members to the newly constructed tile).
2. Define an assignment operator, i.e. define what `Tile& Tile::operator=(const Tile&)` should do (it should call all the `operator=` functions on all its data members and `return *this`).

Now at first glance this seems okay, but I looked at the `sf::Sprite` documentation, and neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator is defined for `sf::Sprite`. It seems sprites can only be created via an `sf::Texture`. Luckily, every `sf::Sprite` exposes a public member function that returns its own bound `sf::Texture`. However, looking at the documentation of `sf::Sprite::getTexture()`, it returns a *pointer* to an `sf::Texture`, which might be `NULL` if no texture is yet bound to `sf::Sprite`. You should check for that in the copy constructor and the assignment operator for `Tile`.

The copy constructor, then, should look something like this:

```
Tile::Tile(const Tile& other)
: type(other.type)
, color(other.color)
, light_level(other.light_level)
, loc_x(other.loc_x)
, loc_y(other.loc_y)
, baseSprite()
{
    sf::Texture* result = other.baseSprite.getTexture();
    if (result)
    {
        baseSprite.setTexture(*result);
    }
}
```

and the assignment operator should look something like this:

```
Tile& Tile::operator = (const Tile& other)
{
    type = other.type;
    color = other.color;
    light_level = other.light_level;
    loc_x = other.loc_x;
    loc_y = other.loc_y;
    sf::Texture* result = other.baseSprite.getTexture();
    if (result)
    {
        baseSprite.setTexture(*result);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

There's more to it than this though, it seems an `sf::Sprite` can also be defined by a sub rectangle of a texture, and it probably has more properties that you need to take care of. For instance, an `sf::Sprite` also has getters and setters for its position, rotation, its global color, all which you need to copy over. In any case, once that's all done, you can forget about the pointer mess and instantiate

```
std::vector<std::vector<Tile> >
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've been trying to implement this solution for a couple hours now. I did finally get the game running using the 2D vector without pointers. However, it loads the tiles much much slower than before. Should this be happening? Anyway, thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I have some ideas on why that's the case, but this chat box is too small for that conversation. You can just email me (see the email address on my profile page) to continue the convo.